# PHP - Pass an Array containing JSON Data through a URL and retrieving using $_REQUEST

Tags: php, http

Hi I'm having an issue where I try and pass a JSON Array through a url to another page and then retrieve the value using $_REQUEST. I've looked at other similar issues here and tried to get it working using http_build_query but still having issues and hoping someone can help me out.

This is the Array containing a JSON object I am trying to pass through. This array is contained in the variable $validationReport:

```
Array([0] => stdClass Object([resourceUri] => file:/home/testFile.txt#//@statements.12/@typeList.0/@enumLiterals.11 [severity] => WARNING [lineNumber] => 333 [column] => 9 [offset] => 7780 [length] => 24 [message] => Name should be less than 20 characters))
```

This is the url I have built:

```
<a href='../../validationReport.php?fileName=$fileName&fileSize=$fileSize&validationReport=$validationReport' target='_blank'>View Validation Report</a>
```

I'm trying to use these values on a different page and I'm using the following code to retrieve the values:

```
 if (isset($_REQUEST['fileName']) && isset($_REQUEST['fileSize']) && isset($_REQUEST['validationReport'])) {
    showReport($_REQUEST['fileName'], $_REQUEST['fileSize'], $_REQUEST['validationReport']);
 }
```

Both fileName and fileSize are set fine and I can get their values but the $_REQUEST['validationReport'] is never set. Can anyone help me to figure out how to pass this value through the URL so that the $_REQUEST['validationReport'] will contain the Array with the JSON Object above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot send an object or display it on webPath

Try this:

json_encode(); to encode it to string

```
<a href='../../validationReport.php?fileName=$fileName&fileSize=$fileSize&validationReport=json_encode($validationReport[0])' target='_blank'>View Validation Report</a>
```

then decode it back to object

```
showReport($_REQUEST['fileName'], $_REQUEST['fileSize'], json_decode($_REQUEST['validationReport']));
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your help, I've tried this but it is still not being recognised as set by the json request. I've encoded it using json_encode and I've passed that value through but no luck with the $_REQUEST['validationReport'] being set.

Comment: The one you have to encode is $validationReport[0] not $validationReport